# matlab - selecting rows when importing

Tags: list, matlab, select

I have a list of values (product codes, like '1123','4356'...), call it LIST,  and I want to select from a matrix M only the correspondent rows. I.e., the first col of the matrix M contains codes, the other cols  the data, and I have an additional vector LIST that contains the codes to select.
 Ex.

```
LIST         MATRIX                I WANT
[123;       [000   1 2 3 ;      [123   3 5 6 ;
 456]        123   3 5 6 ;       456   1 4 6 ]
             000   5 6 7 ;
             456   1 4 6 ]
```

Efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list = [123; 456];
mat = [000 1 2 3; 123 3 5 6; 000 5 6 7; 456 1 4 6];
iwant = [123 3 5 6 ; 456 1 4 6];

[a,b]=ismember(list,mat);
iwant2 = mat(b,:);
iwant==iwant2
```